# How to sketch $\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)=-\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$ in polar coordinates?

Tags: graphing-functions, polar-coordinates, curves

How would one sketch the graph of $$\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)=-\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$ in polar coordinates? I'm aware that polar coordinates involve a radius $r$ and angle $\theta$, such as $r=2-\cos(\theta)$, but in this case we have a cartesian equation. How would we convert this in terms of $r$ and $\theta$? Thanks.

Comment: $x^2+y^2 = r^2$ and $\arctan(y/x) = \theta$

Are you familiar with these formulae?

Comment: @JohnLou Hi John, what process led to those derivations? (it seems straightforward but I still want to know, thanks!)

Comment: The former is derived via the pythagorean theorem (or the distance formula). The same is true of $\theta$. Draw a triangle to help prove this. https://www.mathsisfun.com/polar-cartesian-coordinates.html

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that $\arctan(y/x)$ is only $\theta$ when $-\pi/2 < \theta < \pi/2$.

Comment: So is it just convenient that my equation contains an $x^2+y^2$ and a trig function $\arctan(y/x)$? Otherwise you can't express a Cartesian equation in polar coordinates?

Comment: Well you can, it just requires some more manipulation and it'll look a little uglier.

Comment: Ah, thanks John and Theo :)

Comment: If you're given a cartesian equation, and you wish to write it in terms of polar coordinates, you can use the following substitutions: $$\begin{align*} x &= r\cos(\theta) \\ y &= r\sin(\theta)\end{align*}$$These will transform any equation in cartesian coordinates into polar coordinates.

Comment: @TheoBendit oh wow, that works! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a logarithmic spiral. In the complex plane we have

$$z=e^{-\theta}e^{i\theta}\\
r=e^{-\theta}$$

Thus,

$$
x=\Re(z)=e^{-\theta}\cos\theta\\
y=\Im(z)=e^{-\theta}\sin\theta\\
x^2+y^2=e^{-2\theta}\\
\sqrt{x^2+y^2}=e^{-\theta}\\
\theta=\tan^{-1}\frac{y}{x}\\
$$

So that

$$\ln\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)=-\arctan\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$